# Two maximums of two symmetric polynomials

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, combinatorics, complex-analysis, optimization

I met this problem during my research.

For any fixed integer $t$, let $f_t(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2^t+x_1^tx_2$ and $g_t(x_1,...,x_5)=x_1(x_5+x_2)^t+x_2(x_1+x_3)^t+x_3(x_2+x_4)^t+x_4(x_3+x_5)^t+x_5(x_4+x_1)^t$.

Let $S_k=\{(x_1,...,x_k):x_1,...,x_k\ge0,x_1+\cdots+x_k=1\}$ and
$$c(t)=\max\{f_t(x_1,x_2):(x_1,x_2)\in S_2\},~~d(t)=\max\{g_t(x_1,...,x_5):(x_1,...,x_5)\in S_5\}.$$

**My question is:**

Does there exist some integer $t\ge4$ such that $c(t)<d(t)$?

**Remark:**
It is clear that $g_t(x_1,x_2,0,0,0)=f_t(x_1,x_2)$. So $c(t)\le d(t)$. I did some numerical analysis and found that for $t\in\{4,5,6\}$, the difference between $c(t)$ and $d(t)$ is too small to give me a positive answer (lack of  accuracy). If such $t$ does not exist, maybe there is a theoretic reason.

Any help or discussion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!